# Dialog fragment bundle not passing data

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-bundle

I am opening a dialogfragment and bundling data. I am not sure why but the bundled data does not seem to be past. I have looked for a solution on here but I can't see what I am doing wrong:

This is how I open the fragment and attach the bundled data:

```
FragmentManager fm = ((MainActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
InfoFragment infoFragment = new InfoFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("TITLE", reminder.getReminderTitle());
bundle.putString("DESCRIPTION", reminder.getReminderDescription());
infoFragment.setArguments(bundle);

// Show DialogFragment
infoFragment.show(fm, "InfoFragment");
```

And in the fragment I am retrieving the bundled data like this:\

```
public class InfoFragment extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener{

   TextView titleTextView;
   TextView descriptionTextView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_info, container,false);

        // Iniate ui element
        titleTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.infoFragmentTitleTextView);
        descriptionTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.infoFragmentDescriptionTextView);

        // Get the bundled reminder info to display
        String title = getArguments().getString("TITLE");
        String description = getArguments().getString("DESCRIPTION");

        //Set the values for the textviews from the bundled data
        titleTextView.setText(title);
        descriptionTextView.setText(description);

        return view;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written the below code in my activity and kept the same code in dialog fragment as yours and its working perfectly fine

```
     FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    InfoFragment infoFragment = new InfoFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("TITLE", "Your title");
    bundle.putString("DESCRIPTION", "Your description");
    infoFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    // Show DialogFragment
    infoFragment.show(fm, "InfoFragment");
```

can you tell me where you have written your code to open your fragment

Comment: In an array adapter

Comment: So you need to pass activity instance in your adapter constructor  like 
 public MyArrayAdapter(Activity mActivity) and use mActivity object to getfragmentmanager. try this and let me know if it doesnt works